# feof() и пустой файл

Tags: php

Имеется пустой файл (0 байт). Почему `feof()` не возвращает `true`?

```
<?php
    $f = fopen('file.dat', 'rb');
    echo feof($f);
    fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35136&edit=2

Comment: Насколько я помню, это наследие С. `eof` срабатывает тогда когда происходит ОШИБКА чтения. На С и С++ код строят так, чтобы команда чтения была последней в цикле. Если ошибка - сработает еоф, нет - продолжится цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Представьте, что поток чтения - это чёрный ящик (а в общем так оно и есть). Только попробовав прочитать очередной байт и получив шиш с маслом, узнаешь, что файл кончился...

Answer (score 1):

```
(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
feof — Проверяет, достигнут ли конец файла
bool feof ( resource $handle )
```

Это какбы флаг о том что чтение больше не возможно. Вы попробовали хотябы раз прочитать?? А так лучше берите if(filesize(...) > 0)

```
(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
filesize — Возвращает размер файла
int filesize ( string $filename )
```

Answer (score 0):

feof — Проверяет, достигнут ли конец файла

Comment: Но ведь он уже достигнут, разве не так?

Comment: @Андрей Нет, не так. Представьте, что поток чтения - это чёрный ящик (а в общем так оно и есть). Только попробовав прочитать очередной байт и получив шиш с маслом, узнаешь, что файл кончился...

Comment: @Akina, это в ответ надо было писать.

Comment: Действительно, @Akina, оформите Ваше сообщение как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ок, оформил как ответ.